# How to edit NetworkLobbyManager script (not NetworkManager script) to fit multiple playerprefabs instead of just one?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, networkmanager

I imported unity's [network lobby](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/network-lobby-41836) from assetstore

it has inbuilt ui for game hosting and matchmaking and many custom scripts to manage all the ui elements.

what it doesnt have is ability to add more than one player prefab

I found a [solution](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unet-spawning-different-player-prefabs-solved.387747/#post-2524729)

If I copy paste this code in a new script, it works perfectly.

But problem with new script is I cant make the ui work. So I have to copy paste this code into already provided custom script by unity.

But I dont know how to integrate this code into custom scripts provided by unity.

I tried directly copy pasting the code, but obviously script became full of errors.

I just want multiple player prefabs in unity's inbuilt netowrking ui. Thats it. Please write me a small piece of code that would help me here.

Comment: Please add the code of what you have tried so far and mark where exactly it doesn't behave as expected

Comment: Doess it make sense now ?